# How to zigzag order and concatenate the value every line using python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a result:

```
[[0 0 0 ..., 0 1 0]
 [0 1 1 ..., 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 ..., 0 1 1]
 ..., 
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 1]
 [1 1 1 ..., 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 ..., 1 1 1]]
```

I need to scan the 'result'  in a zigzag order and concatenate the value in a line but i got stuck. 
The zigzag order is shown in the picture.

[Zigzag Order Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIGDj.png)

Comment: For what it's worth, the code you inserted into your post has nothing to do with the question. Your question is only about linearizing your binary numpy array, and has nothing to do with PIL in particular, even though zig-zag scan is common in image proc.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Sorry, the code has been deleted. Yes, it's true, but i got stuck.

Comment: [Zigzagify a Matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75587/zigzagify-a-matrix) on Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you your zigzag:

```
np.concatenate([np.diagonal(a[::-1,:], i)[::(2*(i % 2)-1)] for i in range(1-a.shape[0], a.shape[0])])
```

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Yeah, I'd loose my mind explaining it :D Though it should be "obvious"

Comment: Seems to follow the same explanation offered up here: http://paddy3118.blogspot.com/2008/08/zig-zag.html

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I'll have to trust you on that one, can't access it from work :)